# Bitnodes for node on testnet

Tags: bitcoind, full-node, testnet, bitnodes

I have used the bitnode's own script to install a full node on an Ubuntu 16.04 Digitalocean droplet. I can verify that my node is up and running by checking the IP with port 8333 on Bitnode's [check node](https://bitnodes.earn.com/). However I need a testnet node so I next added the following line to the config file:

```
testnet=1
```

It seems the above line produces the desired effect of turning the node into a testnet node and this can be verified through bitcoin-cli commands. But the node will no longer be accessible from Bitnode. Is Bitnode designed to only work with nodes on the main blockchain or am I missing a necessary step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testnet is a distinct although largely similar protocol.  Bitnodes would need to specifically support it for it to work with it.  I can't find any evidence that bitnodes has any testnet support or a testnet edition.

Comment: This would explain the situation, thank you. Do you have reference on where the two protocols diverge?

Comment: There are many small differences, mostly configured via settings in https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L182

Answer (score 3):

testnet is usually running on port 18333. did you check that port?

Comment: I thought it was `18332`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Using port 18333 has no effect unfortunately and I still get "178.128.162.252:18333 is unreachable."